# How can I import an existing database to my db.py model?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, web2py, database-backups

I have successfully changed the default sqlite connection to mysql. Now I want to import an exported file (database.sql) which is an existing database. I need help on how I can do this please

Comment: Need more details about your question.

Comment: This is my db model of which I changed from the default sqlite in dp.py model of web2py -8 -*
db = DAL('mysql://root:password@localhost/dbname', migrate_enabled = False, pool_size=20) Please I want to import and already exported database so that I can use the tables

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [documentation](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox), you can do:

```
db.export_to_csv_file(open('somefile.csv', 'wb'))

db.import_from_csv_file(open('somefile.csv', 'rb'))
```

Of course, the export operation must happen when you're connected to the original database.